# Do ground sown seeds need to harden off?

Tags: seedlings, hardening-off

It is common knowledge that seedlings grown indoors need to harden off when transitioning outdoors. You need to gradually introduce it to more sun or else it will get fried.

I can't seem to find information on seeds that you sow directly outdoors. Should these type of seeds need to harden off too? I have a feeling that since they are born into full sun, they are somehow already accustomed to the intense light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Hardening off is necessary because you're dramatically changing the environment in which the plant is living. If sown directly outdoors, this is not necessary.